# Getting "column_names must be of same length as tickers" while using ffn

Tags: python

I'm trying to get some prices with the `ffn` (Financial Functions for Python) module like:

```py
import ffn
prices = ffn.get('pltr,msft,dnow', start='2020-04-01')
```

But then when I try to use `column_names` to set my own columns:

```py
prices = ffn.get('pltr,msft,dnow', start='2020-04-01', column_names='aa,bb')
```

And I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in get
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ffn/utils.py", line 34, in _memoize
    cache[key] = result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ffn/data.py", line 99, in get
    raise ValueError("column_names must be of same length as tickers")
ValueError: column_names must be of same length as tickers
```

Why doesn't it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the error string the `column_names` argument have to enumerate the same
number of columns as you have tickers, e.g. 'pltr,msft,dnow'(3) != 'aa,bb'(2).

Or to put it together:

```py
import ffn
prices = ffn.get('pltr,msft,dnow', start='2020-04-01', column_names='aa,bb,cc')
print(prices)
                   aa          bb     cc
Date                                    
2020-09-30   9.500000  209.298721  4.540
2020-10-01   9.460000  211.418289  4.430
2020-10-02   9.200000  205.179031  4.880
2020-10-05   9.030000  209.348495  5.040
2020-10-06   9.900000  204.900406  5.060
...               ...         ...    ...
2021-04-22  22.860001  257.170013  9.490
2021-04-23  23.410000  261.149994  9.540
2021-04-26  24.110001  261.549988  9.710
2021-04-27  23.879999  261.970001  9.590
2021-04-28  23.799999  255.330002  9.925

[145 rows x 3 columns]
```